# Horizontal ng-repeat(er) with new row breaks

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-ng-repeat

Working with Bootstrap and AngularJS, is there a way to `ng-repeat` horizontally with a new row for every set amount of elements?

I have been playing around with `ng-class` to accomplish this <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/8ab5c/6/)</kbd>, but the problem is that I can't get the float left divs within the initial row div... Any thoughts, am I not thinking of something or would this best be done with a Directive?

Here is my code (live example in the above fiddle link):

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="num in numbers" 
            ng-class="{'row': ($index)%2==0, 'col-md-6': ($index)%2!=0}">
            <div ng-class="{'col-md-6': ($index)%2==0}">
                {{num}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```javascript
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
});
```

```css
.row {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want the end result to look like.

Comment: I am. I'm more familiar with Foundations, but same concept. I guess the format that you have it in right now doesn't seem to convey that. Let me work on a fiddle.

Comment: @EnigmaRM I deleted my comment because I thought I could explain it better but you answered before I could add it, so I will leave it alone. I'm starting to think it isn't possible since the repeater element has a closing tag in AngularJS 1.1.5 (What I am using), AngularJS 1.2 has an end repeater tag that would could resolve this, I was waiting for a stable release but I may have to make the jump and fix all my animation. If you find a resolution, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Don't give up, it is possible. And it's true that in 1.1.5 there is a `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` (or something similar). I haven't found a need to use it yet though. And 1.1.5 isn't a stable version either. So if you're already using it, then making the jump to the unstable 1.2 shouldn't be a concern. But there are a fair amount of differences between 1.1.5 and 1.2, hence why I haven't made the move yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was clever what you were doing with `ng-class`. I hadn't ever thought of using `%2` within the expression there.

But for future reference, there is a slightly easier way to accomplish that: [`ng-class-even`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClassEven) and [`ng-class-odd`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClassOdd). It does the same thing as what you were doing, but just a bit cleaner:

```
<div ng-repeat="num in numbers" ng-class-even="'md-col-6'" ng-class-odd="'row'">
    {{num}}
</div>
```

But this doesn't resolve your problem. If I understand you correctly, you want a row, with two columns within that row. The easiest way I could think of is to split up the arrays. Put the repeat on the `div`, then have 2 `span` within the `div`. I think one of the issues that you had originally, is that you were repeating a single `div`, and trying to treat that `block` element as an `inline`

Controller

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.evens = ["2","4","6","8","10","12","14"];
    $scope.odds = ["1","3","5","7","9","11","13"];
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="odd in odds" class="row">
        <span class="span3">{{odd}}</span>
        <span class="span2">{{evens[$index]}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/8ab5c/9/)**

Being that you're using version 1.1.5, that also opens you up to a new directive: [`ng-if`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf)! You could also use [`ng-switch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) to do some conditional logic displays.

You didn't include bootstrap in your fiddle, and for some reason I can't get jsFiddle to display bootstrap. So I created some temp CSS classes that would somewhat resemble bootstraps `class="span"`

Comment: +1 I knew there had to be something for odd and evens, thank you. I was hoping to find something that worked no matter what amount of elements I wanted to repeat horizontally (up to the frameworks limit (generally 12)), for future use. In which case odd and even wouldn't work, however this is a solid resolution for my application. I am going to accept your answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

If you are working with Bootstrap 3 and AngularJS you can declare a new filter that will return one array of sub array slices and then do two ng-repeat.

It will look like that:

```html
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in filtered = (arr | splitArrayFilter:3)">
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="n in row">
          <h3>{{n}}</h3>
        </div>
  </div>
```

```javascript
app.filter('splitArrayFilter', function() {
  return function(arr, lengthofsublist) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(arr) && arr.length > 0) {
      var arrayToReturn = [];  
      var subArray=[]; 
      var pushed=true;      
      for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if ((i+1)%lengthofsublist==0) {
          subArray.push(arr[i]);
          arrayToReturn.push(subArray);
          subArray=[];
          pushed=true;
        } else {
          subArray.push(arr[i]);
          pushed=false;
        }
      }
      if (!pushed)
        arrayToReturn.push(subArray);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayToReturn));
      return arrayToReturn; 
    }
  }
});
```

You can Find it on Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rdyjRtZhzHjWiWDJ8FKJ?p=preview
for some reason the view in plunker does not support bootstrap 3 columns but if you open it in embedded view or in browsers you can see that it works.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks for sharing. Will be using in my current project!

Comment: gives me the error: "Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

Comment: I you don't want to roll your own filter, just add angular-filter to your project and use chunkBy. https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#chunkby Do the filtering in the controller and use track by in the nested ng-repeat with an appropriate key.

Comment: I used the filter in the controller instead of the view  without the angular-filter plugin and thus I got rid of the infinite  $digest. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No need to add .row class .. I did this:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="product in allProducts">
  <div class="my-col-50">
    <h1>{{product.title}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.my-col-50{float:left;width:50%;}
```

and it's work like a charm.

Comment: This doesn't work for uneven height cols which does with the row layout

Answer (score 2):

Although this isn't the "proper" way of doing this, there is a way to achieve this using CSS.

For example, this is for a 3 column layout:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, pod) in stats.pods" class="pod-wrap">
        <div ng-if="objectCheck(pod) == false" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 pod">
            <div>
                <h2 ng-bind="key"></h2>
                <p class="total" ng-bind="pod | number"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="objectCheck(pod) == true" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 pod">
            <div>
                <h2 ng-bind="key"></h2>

                <div ng-repeat="(type, value) in pod track by $index">
                    <p class="status"><% type %> <small><% value %></small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pod-wrap:nth-of-type(3n):after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried two of the suggestions given here... 
the one by yshaool works fine but like i commented on it give me that infinite loop error.

Then I tried something like below:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in split($index, 3, row.Attempts)">
      <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="attempt in row">
          <div>Attempt {{row.AttemptNumber}}</div>
          <div>{{row.Result}}</div>
      </div>              
</div>
```

and the function:

```
$scope.split = function (index, length, attempts) {

       var ret = attempts.slice(index * length, (index * length) + length);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(ret));
       return ret;

}
```

was going somewhere with that when i realized that it could be as simple as

```
<div ng-repeat="attempt in row.Attempts">
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div>Attempt {{attempt.AttemptNumber}}</div>
          <div>{{attempt.Result}}</div>
     </div>                    
</div>
```

using **"col-md-4"** does the trick  as I only need to split using three columns per row..
(let bootstrap do the work!)
anyway the other answers here were really useful...

Comment: Letting bootstrap wrap the columns only works if your column heights are equal. If you have unequal column heights, the wrapping will break and the result is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the number of columns that you need in your template, create chunks of the original data source in your controller.

```
$scope.categories = data //contains your original data source;
$scope.chunkedCategories = [] //will push chunked data into this;
//dividing into chunks of 3 for col-4. You can change this
while ($scope.categories.length > 0)
 $scope.chunkedCategories.push($scope.categories.splice(0, 3));
```

In your template you can now do the following

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="categories in chunkedCategories">
 <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="category in categories">
  <h2>{{category.title}}</h2>
 </div>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to use the $index variable, which is created and updated by AngularJS within an ng-repeat directive, to trigger a call to the CSS clearfix hack which, in turn, resets to a new row.

I am using the following versions: AngularJS 1.5.5 and Bootstrap 3.3.4

```
<!-- use bootstrap's grid structure to create a row -->
<div class="row">

    <!-- Cycle through a list: -->
    <!-- use angular's ng-repeat directive -->
    <div ng-repeat="item in itemList">

        <!-- Start a new row: -->
        <!-- use the css clearfix hack to reset the row -->
        <!-- for every item $index divisible by 3. -->
        <!-- note that $index starts at 0. -->
        <div ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- Create a column: -->
        <!-- since we want 3 "item columns"/row, -->
        <!-- each "item column" corresponds to 4 "Bootstrap columns" -->
        <!-- in Bootstrap's 12-column/row system -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep solution bootstrap formated i solved this using ng-class

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-class="{ 'row': ($index + 1) % 4 == 0 }">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```